# No Authorization header for basic authentication and AllowAnonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, basic-authentication, middleware

I am writing a small authorization service that is going to use basic authentication and JWT authorisation using Net Core 1.1. I've taken a Barry Dorans' sample as a basis for a basic authentication middleware. The thing is that sometimes my service will recieve requests with no authorization header, in which case I would like to allow actions, marked with [AllowAnonymous].

This is the part of `ConfigureServices` to get authorisation working:

```
_services.AddAuthorization(o =>
        {
            ClaimOptions authenticatedClaimOptions = new ClaimOptions(CustomClaimTypes.AUTHENTICATED, true);
            o.AddPolicy(Policies.AUTHENTICATED, p => p.RequireClaim(authenticatedClaimOptions.ClaimType, authenticatedClaimOptions.ClaimValue));

            ClaimOptions tenantMemberClaimOptions = new ClaimOptions(CustomClaimTypes.TENANT_MEMBER, true);
            o.AddPolicy(Policies.TENANT_MEMBER, p => p.RequireClaim(tenantMemberClaimOptions.ClaimType, tenantMemberClaimOptions.ClaimValue));

        });

        _services.AddMvcCore(c =>
        {
            AuthorizationPolicy policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            c.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            // if I uncomment the next line all actions will work as if marked with [AllowAnonymous]
            //c.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
        })
        .AddApiExplorer()
        .AddJsonFormatters(s =>
        {
            s.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

And this is the part of my `Configure` method:

```
var baeh = new BasicAuthenticationEventHandler(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BasicAuthenticationEventHandler>(), _configurationRoot, securityOptions);

        app.UseBasicAuthenticationMiddleware(new BasicAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge    = true,


            Events = new BasicAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidateCredentials = baeh.ValidateCredentialsHandler,
                OnAuthenticationFailed = baeh.AuthenticationFailedHandler
            }
        });

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false,
            TokenValidationParameters = jwtParameters,
            SaveToken = true
        });
```

In my `HandleAuthenticateAsync` I am doing `AuthenticateResult.Skip()` as soon as no Authorization header detected, thus expecting authentication to be skipped by both BasicAuthenticationMiddleware and JwtBearerMiddleware and end up in my `[AllowAnonymous]` action. But each time the header is absent, I end up in `HandleUnauthorizedAsync` handler of my BasicAuthenticationMiddleware. Could anybody, please, explain me, why. I've run out of all ideas so far.

Thank you kindly for any suggestion.